# What is the reason for this Java NullPointerException?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I seem to get a NullPointerException in my code at line 15, but I just cannot understand why. I have been stuck on this for some hour now, and I don't know how to fix it. I have read up on what NullPointerException is, and I think I have a clear grasp of what it is, but I thought my `if`-statement would fix it, but apparently not.

Here is the code:

```
package learning;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Index{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Index indexObject = new Index();
        String filePath = "C:\\Users\\Edvin\\Desktop\\inputPrices.txt";
        Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int average = 0;
        if(indexObject != null){
            average = indexObject.findAverage(getFileInfo(filePath).split(","));
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Object instance is null. Terminating program.");
        }

        int currentItemInput = inputScanner.nextInt();
        if(currentItemInput<average && currentItemInput != 0){

        }
    }

    private static String getFileInfo(String x){
        File listOfPrices = new File(x);
        String error = "An error occurred";
        try{
            BufferedReader getInfo = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(listOfPrices));

            String prices = getInfo.readLine();

            while(prices != null){
                prices = getInfo.readLine();
            }
            return prices;
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("Couldn't find File");
            System.exit(0);
            return error;
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("An I/O error occurred");
            System.exit(0);
            return error;
        }
    }

    public int findAverage(String[] tempIndivPrices){
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int total;
        int [] indivIntPrices = null;
        for(String i : tempIndivPrices){
            indivIntPrices[x] = Integer.parseInt(tempIndivPrices[x]);
            x++;
        }
        for (int element : indivIntPrices){
            total =+ indivIntPrices[element];
            if(element==indivIntPrices.length-1){
                int result = total / indivIntPrices.length;
                System.out.println(result);
                return result;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: No stacktrace needed. Why do you think `int [] indivIntPrices = null;` is going to work?

Comment: Your line contains too much methods calls to clearly see the problems. Change your code (temporarily) so that you call only one method by line, and you'll know exactly whre is the issue.

Comment: `indivIntPrices[x]`? You are indexing in the `null` array.

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring an array but you initialize it to null in this line: `int [] indivIntPrices = null;`

`indivIntPrices` is now a null pointer. You are then trying to access this array two lines later `indivIntPrices[x] = ...` which is not going to work because the variable is not pointing to an array.

To solve this, allocate a new array of integers with the same size as the input array:

```
int [] indivIntPrices = new int[tempIndivPrices.length];
```

Comment: tempIndivPrices.length would look cleaner imo.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check this part of the code:
    getFileInfo(filePath)

Are you getting the properly result of it? It's the only part that you can get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this loop:

```
while(prices != null){
    prices = getInfo.readLine();
}
```

Then, it works.